# Is fiddler correct ? no bytes change after SQL tuning

Tags: fiddler

I had a query Select * from table. Then I changes it to select some_fileds from table.

A json string is made out of these results and fed into grid. I see no bytes difference in fiddler. Does anyone knows why, see the summary below ?

-----Fiddler before SQL change

```
Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      756        (headers:756; body:0)
Bytes Received:  592,133    (headers:279; body:591,854)
```

-----Fiddler after SQL change

```
Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      756        (headers:756; body:0)
Bytes Received:  592,133    (headers:279; body:591,854)
```

Comment: Please provide a link to fiddler

Comment: hi
this is an intranet application. if you were asking link to the website. Sorry did not understood your question.
Thanks'

Comment: I meant this: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the same response I gave when you asked this in the Fiddler discussion forum:

Instead of looking at the **Statistics** tab, instead use the **Inspectors** tab to see the exact content of the response. Or use the **Compare Sessions** command on the context menu of the Web Sessions list (after selecting 2 sessions) to see exactly how those two sessions differ.